# nHibernate many-to-many with meta-value

Tags: c#, nhibernate, many-to-many

I have three entities in my music-related DB: *Video*, *Album* and *Genre*. Both videos and albums can have multiple genres, so I'm trying to link them with *many-to-many* association.
What do I have in DB:

```
Videos:
   Id (int)
   ... (many other columns)

Albums:
   Id (int)
   ... (many other columns)

Genre:
   Id (int)
   Name (string)

Item_Genres: (table we are mapping many-to-many with)
   Id (int)
   objectType (here I have "album" for albums and "video" for videos)
   objectId (id from either Albums or Videos table)
   genreId (Id of the appropriate genre)
```

I can map *Genre* to *Videos* and *Albums* using a many-to-any, but I need to get all the genres for a particular Video.
How can I do that?

At the moment I have that in *Video* mapping:

```
    <set name="Genres" table="item_genres" lazy="true">
        <key>
            <column name="objectId" not-null="true"/>
        </key>
        <many-to-many class="Repositories.Entities.Genre">
            <column name="genreId" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
```

and when asking for *video.Genres* I have genres for that video and for the album with the same Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to define your Video mapping like this:

```
<set name="Genres" table="item_genres" lazy="true" where="objectType = 'video'">
    <key>
        <column name="objectId" not-null="true"/>
    </key>
    <many-to-many class="Repositories.Entities.Genre">
        <column name="genreId" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-many>
</set>
```

The where="objectType = 'video' should make sure you only get videos and not albums.

Comment: And how do you insert new Genres into the list? The objectType column won't be automatically set to 'video'.